# terraform automation of deployment on KVM

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I can't sleep because of this so decided to give it a try here. I'm deploying 4 KVM guests on the same host as my terraform project. I'm following these two guides https://titosoft.github.io/kvm/terraform-and-kvm/ https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9 but I'm still somehow lost.

All I want to achieve is to build n-count of guest machines with names I pre-define in the list e. g. master01, worker01, worker02, worker03. My pool is called guest_images. The qcow2 files, KVM guests and hostnames should be named according to the list.

*UPDATE*
Managed to fix most of my problems. If anyone struggles with the same, here is the code. One last outstanding question: All hostnames currently state "ubuntu". This should be fixed via user_data but that does not work: user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered[count.index]}"
Anyone knows how to fix it?

```
provider "libvirt" {
  uri = "qemu:///system"
}

variable "vm_machines" {
  description = "Create machines with these names"
  type = list(string)
  default = ["master01", "worker01", "worker02", "worker03"]
}

# We fetch the latest ubuntu release image from their mirrors
resource "libvirt_volume" "ubuntu" {
  name = "${var.vm_machines[count.index]}.qcow2"
  count = length(var.vm_machines)
  pool = "guest_images"
  source = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/release-20191008/ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img"
  format = "qcow2"
}

# Create a network for our VMs
resource "libvirt_network" "vm_network" {
   name = "vm_network"
   addresses = ["10.224.1.0/24"]
   dhcp {
        enabled = true
   }
}

# Use CloudInit to add our ssh-key to the instance
resource "libvirt_cloudinit_disk" "commoninit" {
          name = "commoninit.iso"
          pool = "guest_images"
          user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
          network_config = "${data.template_file.network_config.rendered}"
        }

data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/cloud_init.cfg")}"
}

data "template_file" "network_config" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/network_config.cfg")}"
}


# Create the machine
resource "libvirt_domain" "ubuntu" {
  count = length(var.vm_machines)
  name = var.vm_machines[count.index]
  memory = "8196"
  vcpu = 2

  cloudinit = "${libvirt_cloudinit_disk.commoninit.id}"

  network_interface {
    network_id = "${libvirt_network.vm_network.id}"
    network_name = "vm_network"
  }

  # IMPORTANT
  # Ubuntu can hang is a isa-serial is not present at boot time.
  # If you find your CPU 100% and never is available this is why
  console {
    type        = "pty"
    target_port = "0"
    target_type = "serial"
  }

  console {
      type        = "pty"
      target_type = "virtio"
      target_port = "1"
  }

  disk {
       volume_id = libvirt_volume.ubuntu[count.index].id
  }
  graphics {
    type = "vnc"
    listen_type = "address"
    autoport = "true"
  }
}
```